# more than one animation is not possible with tween and three.js

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I tried animating a circle using three.js and tween.js, Now i'm not able to animate for more than one circle, only the recent added circle is animated. what am i missing out in my code here ? and please tell me how i can call those circles one after the other.

```
var circle = createMesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(6, 30, 1.9 * Math.PI, 1.9 * Math.PI));
        // used the function here
        scene.add(circle);

var circle1 = createMesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(2, 10, 1.9 * Math.PI, 1.9 * Math.PI));

        scene.add(circle1);


var position = { x : 0, y: 0 };
        var target = { x : -10, y: 0 };
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(position).to(target, 3000);

tween.start();
            render();
            tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut)
tween.onUpdate(function(){
    circle.position.x = position.x;
    circle.position.y = position.y;
});
tween.onUpdate(function(){
    circle1.position.x = position.x;
    circle1.position.y = position.y;
});

function render(time) {
            stats.update();
            circle.rotation.z = step += 0.008;


              requestAnimationFrame(render);


            TWEEN.update(time);
            webGLRenderer.clear();
            webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the second `tween.onUpdate` callback os overriding the first.
Just add the code to one callback.

```
tween.start();
render();
tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut)
tween.onUpdate(function(){
    circle.position.x = position.x;
    circle.position.y = position.y;
    circle1.position.x = position.x;
    circle1.position.y = position.y;
});
```

Comment: is there anyway i can add both the circles ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this approach takes both of the circles in same direction, i tried changing circle1 xand y values but no result, it stays there, any tweaking for making circle 1 to take an opposite direction ?
i used var position = { x : 0, y: 0 };
        var target = { x : -10, y: 0,x1: 10, y1:-1 };

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it did infact answer the original question. I will change it a bit as to avoid confusion. The code I posted just combines your 2 onUpdate event listeners, not your position code, so if your original did work, it also would have positioned the circles in the same direction.

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me how i can make the Circle1 move to an opposite direction ? like {x:10,y:1} ? in the same fashon, i have stuck at this point

Comment: `circle1.position.x = 0 - position.x;`